# React passing a prop to components return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm really confused as to why when I route to http://localhost:3000/subjects/physics of my project.

The variable gradeSelection is defined in App.js state. It is passed to subjectCards.js component via props as gradeSelection, which passes it onto a Subject.js component via props as gradeSelection.

However, this.props.gradeSelection in Subjects.js returns undefined.

Is there something I might possibly be doing wrong?

Console output:

```
App.js: Year 12             // correct
subjectCards.js: Year 12    // correct
Subject.js: undefined       // not correct
```

App.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    gradeSelection: "Year 12"
  };
}

render() {
  console.log("App: "+this.state.gradeSelection)
  return (
    <Route path="/subjects" render={(props)=>(<SubjectCards {...props}  gradeSelection={this.state.gradeSelection} />)} />
);


}
```

subjectCards.js

```
let display;

console.log("subjectCards.js: "+props.gradeSelection)
display = <Route path="/subjects/:subjectName" render={(props)=><Subject {...props} gradeSelection={props.gradeSelection}/>} />


return (
  display
);
```

Subject.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log("Subject.js: "+this.props.gradeSelection);  // undefined
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

When console.log(props) or console.log(this.props) in Subjects.js constructor. gradeSelection inside the console output is still undefined..

I've tried passing a string to gradeSelection in subjectCards.js and the console output was correct in returning the string in Subject.js..

```
display = <Route path="/subjects/:subjectName" render={(props)=><Subject {...props} gradeSelection={"props.gradeSelection"}/>} />
```

Comment: did you try to log it inside the `componentDidMount` method rather than the constructor?

Comment: I think this is similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496655/props-becoming-null-after-they-are-passed-into-react-component

Comment: change `this.props.gradeSelection` to `props.gradeSelection`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm going to assume that subjectCards.js is a functional component that looks like this. If it's not, could you please post the complete component?

```
function SubjectCards(props) {
  let display

  console.log('subjectCards.js: ' + props.gradeSelection)

  display = (
    <Route
      path="/subjects/:subjectName"
      render={props => (
        <Subject {...props} gradeSelection={props.gradeSelection} />
      )}
    />
  )

  return display
}
```

What I'm seeing wrong with this code in your particular use case is that on line 1, you have an argument with the name of `props`. If you follow the code down to line 9, you'll notice that the anonymous function call inside `render` also has a `props` argument. On line 10, you're calling `props.gradeSelection` which would look inside the argument found on line 9 and not the argument found on line 1, giving you undefined.

There are a couple different ways of fixing this. One way I'd recommend is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your argument `props` on line 1.

```
function SubjectCards({ gradeSelection }) { // See how we went from props to {gradeSelection}
  let display

  console.log('subjectCards.js: ' + gradeSelection)

  display = (
    <Route
      path="/subjects/:subjectName"
      render={props => <Subject {...props} gradeSelection={gradeSelection} />}
    />
  )

  return display
}
```

You can see an example of this over at https://mo9jook5y.codesandbox.io/subjects/math

You can play around with the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mo9jook5y

Answer (score 0):

As Randy Casburn said in the comments, your reference should be to `props.gradeSelection` and not `this.props.gradeSelection`.

Props is received as an input to your constructor function (i.e. `constructor(props)`), and therefore should be referenced as such. If you need to manipulate it before rendering or manage it locally you can pass that to the state for `Subject` within the constructor.

Comment: When console.log(props), gradeSelection is still undefined in there. Would there be any other reason why its undefined?

Comment: Having read your code a little more carefully, it appears that you are overwriting the variable name "prop" is the function scope in subjectCard:
`display = <Route path="/subjects/:subjectName" render={(props)=><Subject {...props} gradeSelection={props.gradeSelection}/>} />`

The props being passed to the `Subject` component is the props defined in the function call, not the props passed to subjectCard.js.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like:

```
//subjectCards.js
render={({gradeSelection, ...other}) => <Subject {...other} 
      gradeSelection={gradeSelection}/>}

//Subject.js
console.log(props.gradeSelection)
```

But wait, you can just simply pass the props, it has all you need (including gradeSelection):

```
//subjectCards.js
render={(props) => <Subject {...props} />}

//Subject.js
console.log(props.gradeSelection)
```